# I need the occurrence of a certain value in a column to match with timestamps (pandas dataframe & csv-file)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, bar-chart

I have a csv-file (called "cameradata") with columns MeetingRoomID, and Time (There are more columns,  but they should not be needed).

I would like to get the number of occurrences a certain MeetingRoomID ("14094020", from the column "MeetingRoomID") is used during one day.  The csv-file luckily only consist of timestamps from one day in the "Time" column. One problem is that the timestamps are in the datetime-format %H:%M:%S and I want to categorize the occurrences by the hour it occured (between 07:00-18:00).

The goal is to have the occurences linked to the hours of the timestamps - in order for me to plot a barplot with (x = "timestamps (hourly)" and y = "a dataframe/series that maps the certain MeetingRoomID with the hour it was used".

How can I get a function for my y-axis that understands that the value_count for ID 14094020 and the timestamps are connected?

So far I've come up with something like this:

```
y = cameradata.set_index('Time').resample('H')     
cameradata['MeetingRoomID'].value_counts()[14094020]
```

My code seems to work if I divide it, but I do not know how to connect it in a syntax-friendly way.

*Clarification:*

The code:  `cameradata['MeetingRoomID'].value_counts().idxmax()` revealed the ID with the most occurrences, so I think I'm onto something there.

Grateful for your help!

[This is how the print of the Dataframe looks like, 'Tid' is time and 'MätplatsID' is what I called MeetingRoomID.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DY7F.png)
*For some reason the "Time" column has added a made-up year and month next to it when I converted it to datetime. I converted in to datetime by: kameradata['Tid'] = pd.to_datetime(kameradata['Tid'], format=('%H:%M:%S'))*

[This is an example of how the output look like in the end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T39Df.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It would be much easier to answer this if you provided code to generate a tiny sample dataframe (5 rows would be enough) and showed what the output dataframe should look like as well.

Comment: Of course! The code and variables are in Swedish but I have done my best to translate and modify the explanation for it to make sense. The output should be a bar chart in the end. So what I need is a y-axis that makes the specific ID "[14094020]" match with my "Time" column.                                                                        I can provide you with a picture of the dataframe print, but I am afraid to confuse you with the additional columns that exist (but should not be adressed) in the Dataframe. Therefore I only wrote that there is two. I will post pictures! Thanks :)